# Configurable DNS cache for Linux

Tags: dns, cache, web

What I need is to configure a Linux machine, so that when user of that machine goes to `www.somesite.com` he/she is redirected to, say, 127.0.0.1.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux has the same host file. Just edit:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Depending on your system a command like this will open up that file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Just put lines like this in there and save:

```
<IP>    <HOSTNAME> <SHORTNAME #1> <SHORTNAME #2> ....
```

For example:

```
192.168.1.1    www.anothersite.com wwwanother
```

Comment: How to achieve the reverse?

Comment: That file will convert `www.anothersite.com` or `wwwanother` to `192.168.1.1` which is what you are looking for.

Comment: should I restart after editing the `hosts` file?

Comment: You should flush your dns cache

http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/07/12/how-to-clear-dns-cache-in-ubuntu-12-04/

and restart your browser. But reboot is another option.

Comment: So without `nscd` the `hosts` file won't work, right?

Comment: @fclad installing the `nscd` made the things work.

Comment: @Acute: `nscd` is not very good for caching name responses. Unbound or dnsmasq are much better for this task.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [override entries on more than one machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/18748), then you could set up a DNS proxy such as [Unbound](http://www.unbound.net) or [DNSmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).